# Is it possible to print pdf files without Adobe installed

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to send pdf files to printer

```
Process p = new Process( );
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( )
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "Print",
    FileName = pdfFilePath
    WindowStyle := ProcessWindowsStyle.Hidden;
    UseShellExecute := true;
};
p.Start( );
```

but i am constantly getting "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation".

I am using Edge to open pdf files (i tried also to set IE and Chrome as default .pdf apps) and i have no pdf reader installed. My question is it possible to send pdf files to the printer directly only with the default windows tools - without installing Acrobat reader etc. ?

Comment: IE and Chrome are using JavaScript libraries to render the PDF. I don't use C#, but do you think it's possible to print the result of a web view?

Comment: I can do this inside the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this library Spire.PDF

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
pdf.LoadFromFile("Sample.pdf");

//Set the printer 
pdf.PrintSettings.PrinterName = "HP LasterJet P1007";

//Only print the second and fourth page
pdf.PrintSettings.SelectSomePages(new int[] { 2,4 });

//Print the pages from 1 to 15
pdf.PrintSettings.SelectPageRange(1,15);

pdf.Print();
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use spire.pdf. I didn't find any option to achieve my initial idea without acrobat reader installed.

Comment: Does Spire.Pdf use Acrobat reader to print a pdf? I found some articles that say they do and others that say they don't...

Comment: Spire PDF is not free and the NuGet library add a watermark to all printed documents, prices is from 999 USD

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach that uses [GemBox.Pdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GemBox.Pdf/), which also doesn't require having Adobe Acrobat installed:

```
using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Load(pdfFilePath))
    document.Print();
```

The above will print your PDF using default printer and print options.
But if needed, you can specify the targeted printer and options like this:

```
using (var document = PdfDocument.Load(pdfFilePath))
{
    var printer = "your printer's name";
    var printOptions = new PrintOptions()
    {
        FromPage = 2,
        ToPage = 4
    };

    document.Print(printer, printOptions);
}
```

You can find more [Print example's here](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-print-pdf/207).

Answer (score 0):

You can Ghostscript which is open source there is a NuGet to use this library in with this program

This NuGet is just a library that interfaces with the Ghostscript library, you need to have Ghostscript installed on the client or add the libraries to the project for it to work

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ghostscript.NET

Example:

```
using (GhostscriptProcessor processor = new 
GhostscriptProcessor())
        {
            List<string> arg = new List<string>() { 
            "-empty",
            "-dPrinted",
            "-dBATCH",
            "-dNOPAUSE",
            "-dNOSAFER",
            "-dNumCopies=1",
            "-sDEVICE=mswinpr2",           
            "-sOutputFile=%printer%" + printerName,
            "-f",
            inputFile};
 
processor.StartProcessing(arg.ToArray(), null);

            
        }
```